# How to match height and width 1:1 in layout android

Tags: android, xml, layout, height, width

I have an imageview in Linearlayout I want its width to be fill_parent. I want its height to be whatever the width ends up being. For example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"

    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But it doesn't show the images in the android layout..
If I force change height of the imageview to 100dp in the code, it works, but I wonder why the height of image doesn't match to width even I wrote constraintDimensionRatio 1:1..

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `weight` to your `imageview` then you will get the `height`, otherwise you have to user `wrap_content` as `height`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:layout_margin="2dp"
tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp" />
</LinearLayout>

 <!--or if you don't want to use weight then user  height = "wrap_content"-->
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use ConstraintLayout as parent and set the dimension you want to make primary and another one to `0dp`.  `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"` means change height and make it 1:1 with width.

```xml
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

      
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```